# Is there any alternative of in operator in where clause for active record query in rails

Tags: sql, database, ruby-on-rails-3

sql query for my rails query is given below...
When I m running query indiviually for each destination id ,total time is less compare to if I run it with in operator.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    requested_trips.id
FROM
    requested_trips
        INNER JOIN
    requested_trips_destinations ON requested_trips_destinations.requested_trip_id = requested_trips.id
        INNER JOIN
    destinations ON destinations.id = requested_trips_destinations.destination_id
WHERE
    (requested_trips.status = 'Active' and requested_trips.trip_stage = 4 
        and (destinations.id in (64,100,545,...)))
```

Comment: Operator in the sense? What operator you are using?

Comment: In operator ...destinations.id in (64,100,545,...)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you will provide = operator and it will be faster. But in case you are using IN operator, you are defining multiple search items. SQL takes time to search all the variables and display the result.

Comment: Is there any alternative way of defining multiple search items? I have to optimize this query.